# Do nodes "TreeView" have unique identifiers (id)?

Tags: c#, winforms

TreeView is created based on files and folders.
 
With each node it is supposed to link the program processes to the node id.
 
**Scenario.**
Files and folders can be deleted (added, renamed) via Windows Explorer.
 
1. Do nodes "TreeView" have unique identifiers (id) or should they be assigned?
Those. so that after deleting (adding, renaming) files (folders), opening (closing) the program id of the remaining nodes did not change.
 
2. If by default the nodes of "TreeView" do not have an ID, then how can you assign their  id?

3. Or to make that when creating "TreeView" the program assigned an ID and put into the "tag", and the files and folders to be deleted (added, renamed) through my application.

   ```
       private void InitFolders()
       {
           //Отключаем любую перерисовку
           //иерархического представления.
           treeView1.BeginUpdate();

           //Инициализируем новую переменную предоставляющую методы экземпляра
           //класса для создания, перемещения и перечисления
           //в каталогах и подкаталогах.
           System.IO.DirectoryInfo di;

           try
           {
               //Вызываем метод GetDirectories с передачей в качестве параметра, пути к выбранной директории. 
               // Данный метод возвращает массив имен подкаталогов. 

               string[] root = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(path);

               //Проходимся по всем полученным подкаталогам.
               foreach (string s in root)
               {
                   try
                   {
                       //Заносим в переменную информацию
                       //о текущей директории.
                       di = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(s);
                       // Вызов метода сканирования с передачей в качестве параметра, информации о текущей директории и объект 
                       // System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeCollection,
                       // который предоставляет узлы дерева, назначенные элементу управления иерархического представления.
                       //

                       BuildTree(di, treeView1.Nodes);
                   }
                   catch { }
               }
           }
           catch { }
           //Разрешаем перерисовку иерархического представления.
           treeView1.EndUpdate();
       }       

       //Процесс получения папок и файлов
       private void BuildTree(System.IO.DirectoryInfo directoryInfo, TreeNodeCollection addInMe)
       {
           //Добавляем новый узел в коллекцию Nodes
           //с именем текущей директории и указанием ключа 
           //со значением "Folder".
           TreeNode curNode = addInMe.Add("Folder", directoryInfo.Name);

           //addInMe.Add(directoryInfo.FullName, directoryInfo.Name, 
           //тут можно указать номер картинки для узла из imageCollection);

           //Перебираем папки.
           foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo subdir in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
           {
               //Запускам процесс получения папок и файлов 
               //с текущей найденной директории.
               BuildTree(subdir, curNode.Nodes);
           }

           //Перебираем файлы
           foreach (System.IO.FileInfo file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
           {
               //Добавляем новый узел в коллекцию Nodes
               //С именем текущей директории и указанием ключа 
               //со значением "File".
               curNode.Nodes.Add("File", file.Name);

               //curNode.Nodes.Add("File", file.Name, 
               //тут можно указать номер картинки для узла из imageCollection);  
           }
       }
       #endregion *** TreeView ***
   ```

Comment: You can set the `Name` or `Tag` properties as you wish.

Comment: They do not, by default, have any kind of ID associated with them. If you need to do that, it is something you'll need to add in the `.Tag` or underlying data source.

Comment: Personally I'd use the `tag` property of the `TreeNode` or look at creating a custom `TreeView`

Comment: Name is a string Tag any object. None are guaranteed to be or stay unique.

Comment: For file system operation you don't need a key. Use `FullPath` property of node.